# Possible misunderstanding of the doFilter method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I am actually pretty new to the Java EE specifications since I am kind of young. I never learned this things at school and I am facing a weird behaviour with the `doFilter` method.

Consider the following filter :

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "URLFilter", value = "/test")
public class URLFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        if (response.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
            response.sendRedirect("/");

        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}

}
```

There is no servlet or page present in `/test` and in my browser, the status is obviously a `404 not found` error when accessing the URL and so should be the value returned to me by the `getStatus()` method which isn't. (actually having a `200` status code)

Why is my filter not redirecting me to `/` as requested ? Do I misunderstand the use of `Filters` in general ?

**UPDATE:**

My question was about redirecting the client (using the `sendRedirect()`) when a page is not found. I did not understand the filter part because I didn't know that `resp` and `req` are actually filled with the new data when `chain.doFilter()` is called. (which I actually found strange since the doFilter is calling the next Filter chained by the COR pattern)

I've made a class inheriting the `HttpServletResponseWrapper`, implemented it, passed it to the Filter and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is invoked before trying to access the actual resource (servlet, page, file, whatever) located at `/test`. So the response status can't be 404 yet at this time.

Then your filter invokes chain.doFilter(), thus telling the container to actually serve the resource at `/test`. Since there is no such resource, you get a 404.

Comment: So the only purpose or filters here is to modifiy requests/reponses before the actual ressources are served?

Comment: No. You can also do things *after* the call to chain.doFilter().

Comment: Yes but then my response get commited and I cannot do something like `sendRedirect()`. I'll guess I have no choice but to make a wrapper to manage what I want.

Comment: You didn't tell what you wanted to achieve. I presume you want to wrap the servlet response, and redirect if you got a 404. Look at HttpServletResponseWrapper.

Comment: Ok this is in fact what I thought. Thanks for the filter clarification, I'll edit my question to be more specific.